# Session is null in MVC4 after OAuth Callback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session-variables

My Controllers derived from my BaseController, it implements ExecuteCore to make OAuth requests. I send Callback (i.e. /Test/CallBack) within the request and save some data in Session. It prompts a page from Provider to Allow or Deny accessing data on Provider server. I click on Accept and it redirects me to /Test/CallBack. In this action method I am trying to get data from Session but session is empty (it is not null, it has lost my data). why? thanks.
OBS: I have tested and added SessionState to Web.config file.

I have created a Web Form project instead of MVC same code works.